# Strange behavior when solving absolute value equations

Tags: equation-solving

Try this:

```
Solve[Abs[x/2 - 1/3] == 1, x]
```

Produces this answer:

```
(* {{x -> -(4/3)}, {x -> 8/3}} *)
```

Now try this:

```
Solve[Abs[2 x - 3] == 7, x]
```

Which gives this error message and answer:

Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>

```
(* {{x -> -2}, {x -> 5}} *)
```

Now I know you can cure the problem like this:

```
Solve[Abs[2 x - 3] == 7, x, Reals]
```

But doesn't it seem strange that they are quite similar and one works and one doesn't?

Comment: A little experimentation suggests that it's the `== 1` that is making it work without spitting out an error: try `Solve[Abs[2 x - 3] == 1, x]`. I can't guess as to why this is.

Comment: Indeed strange, notice in the first case `Solve` doesn't find all the solutions, too. Just try `Reduce[Abs[x/2 - 1/3] == 1, x]`.